# FTP backup script with hard links using

Tags: bash, ftp, backup

Usually I use [rsync based backup](http://www.sanitarium.net/golug/rsync_backups_2010).
But now I have to make backup script from Windows server to linux. 
So, there is no rsync - only FTP.

I like ideas of hard links using to save disk space and incremental backup to minimize traffic.

Is there any similar backup script for ftp instead of rsync?

UPDATE:
I need to backup Windows server through FTP. Backup script executes at Linux backup server.

**SOLUTION:**

I found [this useful script](http://stellarstudios.com/blog/2009-08-11_incremental-website-backup-over-ftp/) to backup through FTP with hard links and incremental feature.

Note for Ubuntu users: there is no `md5` command in Ubuntu. Use `md5sum` instead.

```
#       filehash1="$(md5 -q "$curfile"".gz")"
#       filehash2="$(md5 -q "$mysqltmpfile")"
        filehash1="$(md5sum "$curfile"".gz" | awk '{ print $1 }')"
        filehash2="$(md5sum "$mysqltmpfile" | awk '{ print $1 }')"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit, since the setup was not clear enough for me from the original question.

Based on the update of the question the situation is, that you need to pull the data on the backup server from the windows system via ftp. In this case you could adapt the script you find yourself (see comment) or use a similar idea like:

- Use `cp -lr` to clone the previous backup with hard links.
- Use `lftp --mirror` to overwrite this copy with anything which got updated on the remote system.

But I assumed initially that you need to push the data from the windows system to the backup server, that is the FTP server is on the backup system. This case can not handled this way (original answer follows):

Since FTP has no idea of links at all any transfers will only result in new or overwritten files. The only way would be to using the SITE command to issue site specific commands and deal this way with hard links. But site specific commands are usually restricted heavily so that you can do something like change permissions but not do anything with hard links.

And even if you could support hard links with SITE you have to implement the logic which decides when to use such links. With rsync this logic is built into the rsync server and executed on the server site. With FTP you have to built all the logic at the client site, which means that you would have to download a file to compare it with a local file and then decide if you would need to upload the new file or if a hard link to an existing file could be used.

Comment: I've found [this script](http://stellarstudios.com/blog/2009-08-11_incremental-website-backup-over-ftp/). But I have to understand and check it.

Comment: This script is for a different setup than I understood from your description. Could you please describe more clearly where the script should be run, where the FTP server is and where the backups should be stored? BTW, did you know that there is rsync for windows too?

Comment: I need to backup Windows server through FTP. Backup script executes at Linux backup server. I cant use rsync at the Windows sharing server.

Comment: I've updated the response to show a way to do what you want, based on the script you've found.